# Skip the problematic DAT and proceed with next DATs and out put the error or missed DATs list in separate text file in Perl

Tags: perl

I have another question here, i have several dats and want to merge them. But the script first checks for header of all the DATs and if not matching it will throw error and stop the script. Now i want to run the script skipping the problematic dat and output the error in separate text file with list of errored DAts and reason. Could anyone please help on this. Here is what i have so far:

```
use strict;
my $rootdir = $ARGV[0];
die "usage: perl mergetxtfiles.pl <folder>" if ($#ARGV != 0);
#$rootdir =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;

print "\nFolder = $rootdir\n\n";
opendir(DIR, $rootdir)
    or die "failed opening the directory $rootdir";
open(OF,">:utf8",'combined_'.time.'.dat')
    or die "failed opening the file";

my $icr         = 0;
my $cnt         = 0;
my $header      = '';
my $header_flag = 0;

while(my $fname = readdir(DIR)) {

    # add extensions if needed
    if ($fname =~ m/(\.txt)|(\.dat)|(\.csv)$/i) {

        $icr++;
        my $fnamepath = $rootdir.'\\'.$fname;
        print "\($icr\) $fname\n";
        open(IF, "<:utf8", $fnamepath)
            or die "ERROR: cannot open the file\n$fnamepath "; 

        my $sep_icr = 0;
        while(<IF>) {

            my $line = $_;
            chomp $line;
            next if (/^$/);

            $sep_icr++;
            $cnt++;

            my @ar = split(/\t/,$line);

            if ($cnt == 1) {

                $header_flag = 1;
                $header      = $line;
            }

            if ($sep_icr == 1 and $header_flag == 1) {

                #print "$line \n $header\n";
                if ($line ne $header) {

                    die "Headers are not same\n";
                }
                elsif (($line eq $header) and ($cnt >1)) {

                    print "INFO\: ignoring the same header for $fname \n";
                    $cnt--; 
                    next; 
                }
            }
            print OF $line."\n";
        }
        print "\--Line count= $sep_icr\n\n";
        close IF;
        #print OF "\n";
    }
}

print "\-\-\> Total line count= $cnt\n";
```

Comment: You should know that neither `()`, `-` nor `:` (nor most any character, except the quotation character used, escape sequences like `\n` or backslash itself `\\ `) need to be escaped with backslash in a print statement.

Answer (score 0):

#### Named Loops

In your loop, we have to change your if-clause and the outer loop a bit:

```
FILE:
while(my $fname = readdir(DIR)) {
  ...;
  if ($line ne $header) {
    logger($fname, "Headers not matching");
    next FILE;
  }
  ...;
}
```

In Perl, loops can be labeled, so we can specify which loop we do `next`, instead of setting and checking flags. I used an example logging function `logger`as given below, but you can substitute it with an appropriate print statement.

#### Logging

This is probably a bit more than asked, but here is a little logging function for flexibility. Arguments are a filename, a reason, and an optional severity. You can remove the severity code if it isn't needed. The severity is optional anyway and defaults to `debug`.

```
open my $logfile, ">>", "FILENAME" or die "..."; # open for append
sub logger {
  my ($file, $reason, $severity) = (@_, 'debug');
  $severity = {
    debug => '',
    info  => 'INFO',
    warn  => '!WARN!',
    fatal => '!!!ERROR!!!',
  }->{$severity} // $severity; # transform the severity if it is a name we know
  $severity .= ' ' if length $severity; # append space if we have a severity
  print {$logfile} $severity . qq{$reason while processing "$file"\n};
}
```

If called with `logger("./foo/bar", "Headers not matching", 'warn')` it will output:

```
!WARN! Headers not matching while processing "./foo/bar"
```

Change the printed error message to something more machine-readable if needed.

#### Style tips and tricks:

If find these lines more elegant:

```
die "usage: ...\n" unless @ARGV;
my ($rootdir) = @ARGV;
```

note the newline at the end (supresses the "at line 3" etc). In scalar context, an array returns the array length. In the second line we can avoid array subscripting by assigning in list context. Surplus elements are ignored.

---

Instead

```
if ($fname =~ m/(\.txt)|(\.dat)|(\.csv)$/i) { ...; }
```

we can say

```
next unless $fname =~ m/(?: \.txt | \.dat | \.csv )$/xi;
```

and avoid unneccessary intendation, therefore improving readability.

I modified the regex so that *all* suffixes must come at the end, not only the `.csv` suffix, and added the `/x` modifier so that I can use non-semantic whitespace inside the regex.

---

Windows, and pretty much any OS, understand forward slashes in path names. So instead

```
my $fnamepath = $rootdir.'\\'.$fname;
```

we can write

```
my $fnamepath = "$rootdir/$fname";
```

I find that easier to write and understand.

---

The

```
while(<IF>) {
  my $line = $_;
```

construct can be simplified to

```
while(my $line = <IF>) {...}
```

---

Last but not least, consider starting a habit of using filehandles with `my`. Often, global filehandles are not needed and can cause some bugs.

Comment: Thank you all. I am able to solve the problem with all your suggestions. Thanks again.